# Errors in R Histogram

Tags: r

Can anyone understand why this block of code isn't producing a histogram? Here is the code:

```
incremental <- c()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  set.seed(42)
  avg_2 = mean(runif(100)) 
  incremental <- rbind(incremental, c(avg_2))
}

incremental <- as.numeric(incremental)
hist(incremental, main = "Histogram of Averages From For Loop",
     xlab = "Averages")
```

Don't worry about the set.seed, it is part of the exercise. All the data points will be the same, but nothing shows up on the histogram. Why is this so? Here is a screenshot of the histogram:
[image]

Comment: Because you set the seed for each iteration of the loop, the same value is produced each time. It does actually produce a histogram, but with only 1 bar since all the values are identical

Comment: @JordanHackett my histogram doesn't produce any bars. I will post a screenshot of the graph to show. I was expecting all bars in one bin,

Comment: @MrFlick that worked! Thank you.

Comment: `set.seed(42);incremental <- replicate(1000, mean(runif(100)))`. Followed by the histogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are just looking at a plot with one big bar. It's very hard for R (or anyone) to guess where to create breaks if you only observe one value. Maybe you want something like this:

```
hist(incremental, main = "Histogram of Averages From For Loop", 
    xlab = "Averages", 
    breaks=seq(0,1, length.out=10))
```

This tells `hist()` to create 10 breaks in the range from 0 to 1.